# Choose specific format for hms field token

Tags: 7, rules, tokens

I'm using a token to include an [hms field](https://www.drupal.org/project/hms_field) in an email sent with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules). I'd like to include the hms field in the format `m:ss`, but it's displaying as seconds.

I've tried enabling the custom display setting "Tokens" in the Manage Display tab for the specific Entity containing the field, and choosing the `m:ss` format there, without luck.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: I succeeded in showing the correct formatting as `m:ss` by enabling the module Token and using this token (with low hyphens) `[entityform:field_length]` instead of `[entityform:field-length]`.